# What piezoelectric materials can be made at home?

Tags: materials, electricity

I would like to know a few examples of transparent materials which exhibit piezoelectricity and can be purchased online or synthesized at home with ease.

Answer (score 13):

The top of my list for exhibiting piezo activity and can be easily purchased and is also transparent..

Quartz

That's about it. It's used everywhere - as an oscillator for quartz crystal watches, quartz crystal microbalances, etc.

Most of the other piezoelectric options:

- Lead Zirconium Titanate (PZT)
- Barium Titanate ($\ce{BaTiO3}$)
- Zinc Oxide ($\ce{ZnO}$)

Aren't transparent. They're white ceramics. You can easily purchase them online from most scientific supply companies, but they don't meet your transparency criteria.

Polyvinylidene difluoride (PVDF) is claimed to be transparent (e.g., [here](http://www.westlakeplastics.com/pdf/film_pvdf.pdf)) but you would need to apply a high electric field to pole it, and if the formulation isn't crystalline enough, you may not get a high piezo response.

My group is designing some materials that would be good, but they're still in the research stage. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 2):

[Rochelle salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_sodium_tartrate) (potassium sodium tartrate tetrahydrate) exhibits piezoelectricity and forms transparent crystals.

It should be available from drug stores or online.